# How to get axis property with Revit API?

Tags: python, api, revit-api, revit

I am trying to used the Revit Interactive Python Shell to rotate an object in Revit. I am hung up on how to designate the axis of rotation. I don't know how to create a line with the API and then designate an axis in ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement()

The third argument in RotateElement() is the axis. I am creating a line but I am not sure if I am designating its axis in the third argument of .RotateElement()

When I run this code nothing happens. This is even the case if I have a wall selected. Please let me know if anything needs clarification.

Thanks,

```
import clr
import math
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI') 
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI') 
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import * 

def pickobject():
    from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import ObjectType
    __window__.Hide()
    picked = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element)
    __window__.Show()
    __window__.Topmost = True
    return picked

#set the active Revit application and document
app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

#define a transaction variable and describe the transaction
t = Transaction(doc, 'This is my new transaction')

#start a transaction in the Revit database
t.Start()

#perform some action here...

el = pickobject()    

p1 = XYZ(0,0,0)
p2 = XYZ(0,0,1)
myLine = Line.CreateBound(p1, p2)

ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement(doc, el.ElementId, myLine, math.pi / 2)

#commit the transaction to the Revit database
t.Commit()

#close the script window
__window__.Close()
```

It turns out I wasn't properly selecting an element or converting degrees to radians. After doing these things I was able to make my selected element rotate 90 degrees. The only problem I face now is choosing the origin at which the element rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing wrong is the angle.
This needs to be in radians. In your example that would be π/2.
See [here](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/3968f4e8-759c-f975-6c1f-7de42be633ed.htm)

Comment: Hello Jan, thank you for taking the time to look into this. I changed the angle to math.pi / 2. However, the wall still does not rotate. Does the Rotate Element method only work on basic geometry?

Comment: @ChristianGentry I see you got the rotation working, but are struggling with the rotation origin? You'll just have to change the X and Y coordinates of p1 and p2 in your code to the origin point if you want to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python script looks perfectly all right to me, once the `90` degrees have been replaced by `0.5 * pi` radians. You can compare it with this similar snippet of working sample code used for a [Creative Workaround to Rotate Elevation Marker in Chunks](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/08/wall-profile-command-update.html#5).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! The reason it wasn't working was because I hadn't converted to radians and I also hadn't properly selected the element. Now my only issue is specifying the rotation origin.

Comment: Good to hear. The rotation axis defined by `myLine` defines the rotation origin and direction.